# Add a struct pointer to the end of a pointer of structs

Tags: c, pointers, reference, struct, allocation

I've searched through the forums for awhile, but can't seem to get this problem fixed. It compiles and does almost everything I need it to do, but one thing is off. Whenever I update a chore_array, which is a **pointer of pointers to struct chore**, the new update replaces all previous assignments.

```
typdef struct _chore{
    char *chore_name;
    int number;
    char *due_date;
    }chore;
typedef struct _chorelist{
    chore **chore_array;
    int occupied_number;
    int size_of_array;
    }chorelist;

void addChoreToLast(chorelist *chore_list,chore *chore_input)
{
  if(chore_list->occupied_number < chore_list->size_of_array)
  {
      chore_list->chore_array[chore_list->occupied_number]=chore_input;
      chore_list->occupied_number++;
  }
  else
  {
      chorelist *pChoreList = (struct _chorelist*)malloc(sizeof(struct _chorelist)*chore_list->occupied_number);
      memcpy(pChoreList,chore_list,sizeof(struct _chorelist*)+sizeof(struct _chore*)+1);
      pChoreList = chore_list;
      pChoreList->chore_array[pChoreList->occupied_number]=chore_input;
      pChoreList->occupied_number++;
  }
```

Code Input:

```
Enter chore name      : Dishes
Enter chore number    : 1
Enter Date to complete: 04/21/2013

Enter another chore   : Sweeping
Enter chore number    : 4
Enter Date to complete: 05/02/2013
```

Code Output:

```
Entered Chores are    : Sweeping,   Chore Number: 1, Date: 04/21/2013
                        Sweeping,   Chore Number: 4, Date: 05/02/2013
```

Desired Output:

```
Entered Chores are    : Dishes,     Chore Number: 1, Date: 04/21/2013
                        Sweeping,   Chore Number: 4, Date: 05/02/2013
```

In my main function, which is essentially given and cannot change, it calls a function that initializes **chorelist** and allocates memory to each member of the **chorelist** struct so that I can assign values and character strings to each of its members. 
My problem is that the name of the chore gets replaced after each call of the function, which takes in an already established chore list.

Is my assignment statement in **addChoreToLast** off? Thanks in advance

Comment: `memcpy(pChoreList,chore_list,sizeof(struct _chorelist*)+sizeof(struct _chore*)+1);` You forgot to multiply by the number of occupied slots. BTW: realloc() is easier in this case.

Comment: Indeed, realloc is necessary: you should free the old list, but in any case, the whole of the else block is jumbled and incorrect (you're setting the wrong variables).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `realloc`:

```
void addChoreToLast(chorelist *chore_list,chore *chore_input) {
    chore **p = NULL;
    if(chore_list->occupied_number == chore_list->size_of_array) {
        p = realloc(chore_list->chore_array, (chore_list->size_of_array + 1) * sizeof(chore *));
        if(!p) {
            perror("Can not allocate memory");
            return;
        }

        chore_list->size_of_array++;
        chore_list->chore_array = p;
    }
    chore_list->chore_array[chore_list->occupied_number]=chore_input;
    chore_list->occupied_number++;
}
```